# Let flash messages disappear in the same page in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the flash message disappear after a few seconds. So I use these codes:

```
$(function() {
  $('.alert').slideUp(1500);
});
```

.alert is the bootstrap class I add to the flash message.

And my app achieved user login/logout function only through omniauth. (with facebook and google plus) The login/logout codes listed in the end.

When I log in, the flash message disappeared like what I thought. But when I log out, the flash didn't disappear.

But if I use these codes, this function will work correctly. (but slightly different than what I want)

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.alert').slideUp(500);
  }, 1000);
});
```

login/out codes:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    auth_data = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    auth = Authorization.find_by( provider: auth_data['provider'], uid: auth_data['uid'] ) 
    user = auth.nil? ? User.create_with_omniauth(auth_data) : auth.user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    if !user.email
      redirect_to edit_user_path(user), :alert => "Please enter your email address."
    else
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed out!"
  end

  def new
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => "Authentication error: #{params[:message].humanize}"
  end
end
```

Comment: That's pretty heavy-handed to keep a timer running when a single-shot at the end of a page load should do it. Are you sure it's not because you're using `notice` for the logout message?

Comment: If this is a Rails 4 app, it might be because of turbolinks. You need to bind your function to `page:load` as well as `ready` (or disable turbolinks)

Comment: I use notice for both logout and login, as the SessionsController shows.

Comment: Did @LoganSerman means this?
`
$(document).bind("load ready", function(){
  $('.alert').slideUp(1500);
});
`
But this code didn't work, either.

Comment: `page:load`, not `load`.

Comment: It actually works! Thank you very much. Would you be the answerer? And why can't I found related document on jquery site?

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.alert').slideUp(500);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Where should this go? I tried to add it to my `application.js` and my `_header.html.erb` but it did not work. Just for information, I do have jQuery working in my app, thanks to `//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs` in `application.js`. Am I missing something?

Comment: So simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Previously I had same problem,But now solved through this:
**Try this in your code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.alert').fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem it is recommended to use toastr.js. It provides an toasting behavior and with a few changes it works perfectly with bootstrap an rails flash messages. It is fully customizable, easy to use and has some more advantages in addition.

**1. Step**

Download [toastr.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.css) and [toastr.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.js), place the CSS-file in the *app/assets/stylesheets* directory and the JS-file in *app/assets/javascripts*.

**2. Step**

Open the [toastr demo webseite](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html#) and set up the toasting messages for your needs. Copy the javascript code below on that page, without the first line, to your *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*. (For code styling purposes you can put this code in new JS-file, if you want).

It should look like this (the values may differ a bit):

```
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
```

**3. Step**

Require *toastr.js* in your *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* at the end of the comment:

```
//= require toastr
```

and require the *toastr.css* in your *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css* as well:

```
*= require toastr
```

From now on you can toast messages very easy from any file with a single line of code:

```
toastr["success"]("This is what i want to toast!");
```

**4.Step**

In this step we tell rails to fire up a toast when a flash message is set:
Delete the existing flash message tag in the *app/views/layouts/application.html.erb* and replace it with the following code:

```
<% unless flash.empty? %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <% flash.each do |f| %>
      <% type = f[0].gsub('alert', 'error').gsub('notice', 'info') %>
            toastr['<%= (type == 'danger' ? 'error' : type) %>']('<%= f[1] %>', '<%= type %>');
        <% end %>
    </script>
<% end %>
```

It looks up if a flash message is available and if it is, its message is shown within a toast in the way you defined in step 2.

**5. Step**

Additionally the Toast style can be changed to bootstrap style in a very simple way:
In *toaster.css* change he following statement:

```
#toast-container > div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
  width: 300px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background-position: 15px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

to this:

```
#toast-container > div {
      width: 300px;
    }
```

That's all. Now every flash message is toasted, so that it disappears after the period of time you specified in the *toastr.options*.

To set a flash message you just need the following ruby code. Instead of `:warning` you can use the bootstrap alert identifiers (`:danger`, `:warning`, `:info`, `:success`).

```
flash.now[:warning] = "This is an important warning"
```