# Rails - stacking flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My page is using remote calls to render the content (each time a button is clicked), so there are no postbacks.

I generate a flash notice like this in the controller action:

```
if @something.save
          format.html { redirect_to some_other_path(@this,@that), notice: t('messages.messages.great_success')}
          format.js { flash[:notice] = t('messages.messages.great_success') }
```

Now I had an issue where the notice would not go away so I added this JS code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $('.alert-info').slideUp();
    }, 5000);
});
```

But it seems that on my page the user can click the button which can call the controller
action multiple times, so I need to be able to "stack" the error messages one of top of each other.

Is there a Rails way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "stack"?  When I've needed flash messages in a remote call, I've found it easiest to construct them manually in the JS callback.  You can decide there if you want to remove all previous messages each time, etc.

Comment: just have one on top of each other if the user performs the actions lots of times....

Comment: OK I posted code I use for a similar use case as an answer (a bit too much code for a comment).  Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but this is how I am generating Flash-like messages in my JS callback (.js.erb):

`<% if @slot.errors.any? %>
  var build_error = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='build_error'>";
  build_error += "The form contains <%= pluralize(@slot.errors.count, 'error') %>.";
  build_error +=   "<ul id='error_explanation'>";
  <% @slot.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    build_error += "<li><%= j msg %></li>";
  <% end %>
  build_error +=   "</ul>";
  build_error += "</div>";
  $(build_error).insertBefore( "#edit_slot_<%= @slot.id %>" );
<% else %>
  $('#signup-modal-<%= @slot.id %>').modal_success();
<% end %>`

This should give you the general idea - just build the message using the same classes you use to display Flash messages and then insert them where you want them in your DOM so that appear as expected.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use [toastr.js](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html#). It manages stacking and diappearing of messages. How to use it with flash messages in rails I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949948/let-flash-messages-disappear-in-the-same-page-in-rails/36795937#36795937).